# Determine when an FTP uploaded file is ready for processing using FileSystemWatcher

Tags: .net, file-upload, ftp, filesystemwatcher

I want users to be able to upload files via FTP to my site (IIS 7.5).  Once the file is uploaded, then I want to process the file using FileSystemWatcher.  How can you determine when the file has completed uploading to the server?  I don't want to process it before it completes the entire upload.

Comment: How could you possibly know that unless you know the size of the file beforehand?

Comment: @JJD it could be fixed format or something where it is possible to determine if end of file is reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no inherent way that you can know the file has completed uploading. It is even possible that it is uploaded partially first and completed later.

You either need to determine from the file contents that it is a complete file or use some other marker. For example an empty file signifying completion, i.e. user first uploads `file1.dat` and then uploads `file1.done` to signal that `file1.dat` can now be processed.

Comment: Same answer as mine but more concise and you beat me to it. +1

Comment: @DavidStratton Thanks. Sometime elaborate is better :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS 7.5 and above you can write an FTP provider that can kick off a process - this wouldn't use File System Watcher but probably provides a better alternative.

Here is a guide on IIS that shows an example (of sending an notification email in this case) that you can adapt to your purposes.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/632/how-to-use-managed-code-c-to-create-an-ftp-provider-that-sends-an-email-when-files-are-uploaded/

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could check the file size every second and if it doesn't increase for a while maybe the transfer is ready.