# How to monitor FTP incoming folder for newly uploaded files?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, system.reactive

In other words, how can I kick off some custom processing of newly uploaded files to FTP server on my machine with IIS-backed FTP server and .NET?

*Clarification* 
This is to run on the machine that hosts FTP server.  Permissions are not an issue in my case.

[It seems I'd need to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9895839/90475) the uploading entities to add a listing file that is sent after the actual data file is completely uploaded.  Imagine that there is an actual xxx.data file uploaded, followed by xxx.listing file that signifies completion of xxx.data file upload.

Originally this question was talking about Reactive Extensions.  I was hoping that someone has a bridge from IIS 7.5's FTP server to Reactive Extensions, so I can focus on the higher-level implementation details.

Comment: See this Code Project article for a complete description of using `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F

Comment: Your question says 'FTP server on my machine' which implies you would have access to the directories it serves from, and could use the FileSystemWatcher technique.   I am sorry I gave you bad information based on that--suggest you make it clear it is a non-local FTP server.   I am not aware of any protocol that would make changes to a foreign FTP server observable; you will have to poll.

Comment: Also check this Pub/sub sample using HTTP polling duplex WCF channel http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/07/pubsub-sample-using-http-polling-duplex.html

Comment: Are you looking to scan the FTP directory, or are you looking to scan a networked drive?

Comment: @casperOne I am looking to scan the FTP incoming folder on my machine, given admin rights.

Comment: you can try this FileSystemWatcher Using Rx  http://krishnapotluri.blogspot.in/2010/10/filesystemwatcher-using-rx.html .. sorry misunderstood the question at first..

Comment: Ok i will give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've slimmed down the [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229241%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) to focus in on file creation, as it's the only event of interest when files are uploaded to FTP server.

One would have to install the [Reactive Extensions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main) for this code sample to work in Visual Studio 2012.

```
 class Program
 {
     static void Main()
     {
         // Create a FileSystemWatcher to watch the FTP incoming directory for creation of listing file

         using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\FTP-Data\Incoming", "*.lst"))
         {
             // Use the FromEvent operator to setup a subscription to the Created event.           
             //                                                                                    
             // The first lambda expression performs the conversion of Action<FileSystemEventArgs> 
             // to FileSystemEventHandler. The FileSystemEventHandler just calls the handler       
             // passing the FileSystemEventArgs.                                                   
             //                                                                                    
             // The other lambda expressions add and remove the FileSystemEventHandler to and from 
             // the event.                                                                         

             var fileCreationObservable = Observable.FromEvent<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                                         UseOnlyTheSecondArgument,
                                         fsHandler => watcher.Created += fsHandler,
                                         fsHandler => watcher.Created -= fsHandler);

             fileCreationObservable.Subscribe(ActionWhenFileIsUploaded);

             watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

             Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit the program...\n");
             Console.ReadLine();
         }
     }

     private static void ActionWhenFileIsUploaded(FileSystemEventArgs args)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} was created.", args.FullPath);

         // TODO
         // 1. Deduce original file name from the listing file info
         // 2. Consume the data file
         // 3. Remove listing file
     }

     private static FileSystemEventHandler UseOnlyTheSecondArgument(Action<FileSystemEventArgs> handler)
     {
         return (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) => handler(e);
     }
 }
```

I am still working out the details of transforming observable of listing files to observable of actual data files.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 2):

Rx **isn't** a good fit, per se.

Rx is a good fit when you want to query events (or collections in time) and you want to compose complex filtering, joining and projection.

Rx does absolutely nothing with regard to watching FTP uploads or file system changes. Or any event source really. It does **not** provide any mechanism to generate those types of events.

Instead it does allow a way to bring together all sorts of different event sources - events, async operations, WMI events, generated observables, etc - into a common framework.

You need to look at something like `FileSystemWatcher` and then turn this into an observable.

Then you can do some awesome things with Rx. Truly awesome.

Comment: Thanks for laying out the development path for me.

Comment: No worries. I love using Rx. It's awesome. It's worth learning to get its power. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To know that a new file is complete, a frequent pattern is that the client uploads the file in a TEMP directory, then it does an FTP move command. The move (or a rename) is atomic IF the source and target directories are on the same partition.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend the capabilities of FileWatcher i.e. to check if your file was completely uploaded (or not) and then use the Rx samples listed in the comments.

Or..

Not directly watch the files in FTP folder.. instead run a windows service  or some app to *copy* the fully uploaded file to a **processing folder**, then you are sure that only there are no partial files. (will need to figure out how. Wonder if a file is locked for the period it is uploading the server ) . This separates watching and processing logic in separate apps.(but makes it trickier.) . Also after processing you can move the file out the processing folder so that you don't process the same file again(or you can use some other logic.)